# Comparing whether a unicode equals something

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'd like to add some logic to my code along the lines of:

```js
var X = $('span').text()
$('body').append(X)

if (X == '&#9660;') {
  $('body').append('Yay!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>&#9660;</span>
```

However, as you can see from the above snippet, "Yay!" isn't appended to the body. So how can I check if a unicode character equals an escape sequence?

Comment: And, what's the question?... Everything seems to work...

Comment: Problem is? http://jsfiddle.net/dhyu891w/

Comment: You've changed my == to !== so that's why it's returning a true value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use charCodeAt(0) and omit the '&#' in your string:

```
if ( X.charCodeAt(0) == 9660 ) {
  $('body').append('Yay!');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.fromCharCode()` to create the character using the decimal number so that it matches the HTML entity you're using. Or just copy the character into a string literal and compare directly. This may be clearer or not depending on your situation.

```js
var X = $('span').text()
$('body').append(X)


if (X == String.fromCharCode(9660)) {
  $('body').append('Yay!')
}

if (X == "▼") {
  $('body').append('Yay!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>&#9660;</span>
```

Comment: I can stop crying now.

Comment: I just updated. You can also simply use a string literal by copy/pasting the character from your browser into a JS string.

Comment: Triple equals works as well.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can escape unicode characters with `\u` followed by the *hexidecimal* representation of the unicode value. See [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm) for the conversion of your character. Near the bottom of the page it gives the Java escape code for the character which is the same as the JavaScript one.

```js
var X = $('span').text()
$('body').append(X)
if (X == '\u25bc') {
  $('body').append('Yay!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>&#9660;</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel! I like the String.fromCharCode solution better, but yours works for sure.

Comment: I like that solution better too