# How do you check if string is equal to unicode character?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, unicode

I'm working on an add-on for Firefox that will convert user selected temperatures. Basically it loops through each character of the user's selection and determines whether it is a number, negative or decimal using if statements. Once it locates the degree symbol, I want the program to stop looping through the characters and save the number that it has pulled from the user selection.

However, since the degree symbol is a unicode character, the if statement doesn't detect the degree symbol and evaluates the statement to false. Because I have other fail-safes in place, it doesn't infinite loop.

My statement is `if (str.charAt(#) == "°")` but it won't evaluate to true. My test HTML file uses both the `°` unicode just pasted in and also the `&deg;` code. Neither will trigger the statement to be true.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/q/31325410/6309 help?

Comment: You could use a regex for pattern matching in strings. Search for "RegExp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me:

```js
var str = document.getElementById('thing').innerText;
console.log(str.charAt(0) === "°");
```

```html
<span id="thing">&deg;</span>
```

Comment: It isn't working on my end, but I did try applying the code directly to my test page and it worked there, but for some reason the code inside of the Firefox extension file will not evaluate true. Strange. I'll have to get in touch with the other AMO guys and see if we can figure it out.